# Setting boxplot properties

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to adjust the heights of a boxplot.  Simple example:

```
boxplot(1:10,[zeros(1,5) ones(1,5)], 'colorgroup', [0 1], 'colors', 'rb', 'orientation', 'horizontal') 
h = findobj(gcf, 'tag', 'Box'); 
ydata = get(h, 'YData');
celldisp(ydata);
ydata{1} = ydata{1}*0.60;  % adjust height
set(h, 'YData', ydata);
```

Note that `celldisp(ydata)` displays:

```
ydata{1} =
    1.8500    1.8500    2.1500    2.1500    1.8500
ydata{2} =
    0.8500    0.8500    1.1500    1.1500    0.8500
```

And the above code gives the error:

```
Error using set
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

How do I set 'YData', as it is a cell?

---

Please note, this is a simplified extraction from much more complicated code. In general, the elements of the cell ydata are **NOT** all the same length, hence you cannot just use `cell2mat` or something on ydata

Comment: What happens if you try `set(h, {'YData'}, ydata);` instead? (It works without error, but I'm not quite sure if that's what you try to achieve.)

Comment: how did you solve the problem now?

Comment: @thewaywewalk  `h` is actually an **array** of handles.  So you manpiluate each `ydata` separately and write back separately.  e.g. `ydata = get(h(1), 'YData');` etcc, then `ydata = get(h(2), 'Ydata');` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `h` is an **array** of handles, since there are multiple objects in this figure.

Thus, the manipulations must be performed in each entry in the **array** `h` separately.

e.g.

```
ydata = get(h(1), 'YData');
% do stuff to ydata,
set(h(1), 'YData', ydata);

ydata = get(h(2), 'YData');
% do stuff to ydata,
set(h(2), 'YData', ydata);
```